# QBXML, QGFC - How do I retrieve Service Item Descriptions

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, qbfc

I am attempting to retrieve Service Items from Quickbooks.

When retrieving `ItemInventoryRetList`, I get some properties to work with, including `SalesDescription`.

ItemInventoryRetList does however not return Service Items.

When running an `ItemNonInventryRetList` or `ItemServiceRetList`, I don't get any `Description` properties from QBFC classes.

Looking at the response, I see it looks like I have to access the SalesorPurchase. aggregate to get at the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, got it sorted. Seems the On Screen Reference REALLY is your friend...

QBFC already builds the properties when the RetList is populated. Nice... I was under the impression I had to iterate through a "list" of sub aggregates/nodes in the RetElement.

Using the following, works a charm.

```
RetListObject(withid).name.GetValue (etc)
'Sub Properties in Response
RetListObject(withid).ORSalesPurchase.SalesOrPurchase.Desc.GetValue
RetListObject(withid).ORSalesPurchase.SalesOrPurchase.ORPrice.Price.GetValue
```